# How do I divide a string into three parts?

Tags: vb6

I want to divide a string into three parts. I am using following code.

```
dim length1 as string 
dim length2 as string
dim lenght3 as string

length1=Mid$(Text1.text,1,30)
length2=Mid$(Text1.text,31,70)
length3=Mid$(Text1.text,71,100)

msgbox length1
msgbox lenght2
msgbox length3
```

msgbox 2 show me the length of 11,30. Why?

What I have tried:

What have wrong with my code? I know that Mid$ start at the left of the string.

Comment: i have completed all my project except this topic.please help me

Comment: No Man. I want to divide a string in three parts. But when i use Mid$(text1.text,20,30)  for third part , msgbox show me total of both.

Comment: Suppose text1 contain 100 characters. I want that msgbox 1 show 1 to 30 characters , msgbox 2 show next 31 to 70 characters and msgbox 3 show further 71 to 100 Characters.Thanks

Comment: Just to let you know, if you don't comment on my question below I do not receive notifications of any changes you need to be made.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are wanting each string to be 10 characters long? Your problem appears to be that you keep changing the length of the string by 10.

Edit: Since OP provided more information in his comments, I updated code to accommodate request.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim length1 As String
    Dim length2 As String
    Dim length3 As String
    Dim divTot As Integer, leftOver As Integer

    divTot = Len(text1.Text) / 3
    leftOver = Len(text1.Text) - (divTot * 2)

    length1 = Mid$(text1.Text, 1, divTot)
    length2 = Mid$(text1.Text, divTot + 1, divTot)
    length3 = Mid$(Text1.Text, (divTot * 2) + 1, leftOver)

    MsgBox length1
    MsgBox length2
    MsgBox length3

End Sub
```

Comment: Excellent . Thanks brother